# Receive input from Android application EditText and send to Kafka

Tags: android, kotlin, apache-kafka

The language used is Kotlin, implemented by Android Studio.
I want to change the EditText existing in the xml of the layout folder into String type and send it as Kafka value, but I keep getting an error somewhere.
It is said that it is impossible to conclude the visible error theory. Where exactly is the problem?

```
class Registration() : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.Sign_Up)


        val rc: Button = findViewById(R.id.Registration_Completed)

        val id: EditText = findViewById(R.id.ID)
        val pw: EditText = findViewById(R.id.PW)

        val UserID = id.text.toString()  //convert id to string
        val UserPW = pw.text.toString()  //convert pw to string

        rc.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, next_activity::class.java)
            Producer()
            Toast.makeText(this,  "registration completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            startActivity(intent)
        }
}
```

Below is the Producer code

```
class Producer {    
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: String){
            val TOPIC= "test"
            val SERVERS  = "localhost:9092"

            val configs = Properties()

            configs.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, SERVERS)
            configs.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
            configs.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    
          val producer = KafkaProducer<String, String>(configs)

          var record: ProducerRecord<String, String> =ProducerRecord(TOPIC,"print")
```

Up to this point, the output is normal.

```
          producer.send(ProducerRecord(TOPIC, UserID))
          producer.send(ProducerRecord(TOPIC, UserPW))
          producer.close()


          try {
              producer.send(ProducerRecord<String, String> (TOPIC, "SUCCESS!"))
          } catch (exception:Exception)
          {
              exception.printStackTrace()
          }
          finally { producer.close() }
```

The connection may not work well because the cord is partially cut.

I used the id and pw variables in the Producer by dragging the EditText to Internal fun() under the Registration class.
Producer and connection, how to pull variables, etc., function errors, etc. Which is the problem?

Comment: Can you be more precise by what you mean with "an error"?

Comment: I am getting an error like this [ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) ]